# Camunda: Test whether JSON array contains an element

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-spin

I would like a conditional flow to depend on whether a JSON attribute (containing a JSON array of strings) contains a specific element.

The following expression works if the element is present, but throws an exception if it is not:

```
   <bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">
       ${ json_array.indexOf("foo")!=-1 } 
   </bpmn:conditionExpression>
```

The equivalent expression with `lastIndexOf()` also fails despite [the documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.camunda.spin/camunda-spin-core/1.5.6/org/camunda/spin/json/SpinJsonNode.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)) claiming that should not happen ([issue 134](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-spin/issues/134)).

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With Camunda 7.17.0+ you can use

```
    <bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">
       ${ json_array.contains("foo") } 
    </bpmn:conditionExpression>
```